# Pairing unsuccesful for iphones

Tags: iphone, backup, bluetooth

I have an iPhone6 that I am trying to pair with an iPhone12 as part of transferring the apps and settings. Both are on the same wifi network and both are able to see each other on Bluetooth.

However I get the message `Pairing Unsuccessful`:

> *Pairing Unsuccessful*
>
> Make sure "my-iphone" is turned on, in range, and is ready to pair"

where "my-iphone" has the name of the other iphone for both of the devices.  Both of the iPhones are also able to pair with other bluetooth devices such as headsets. Thus the pairing problem is specific to pairing with another iPhone and not more general.

So why are they apparently not "ready to pair" with each other?

Comment: Honest question... do iPhones *ever* pair with each other?  The problem is, of course, the iP6, which can't run an iOS late enough to support the modern phone-to-phone migration path.  You can't just back up the iP6 and restore the backup to the iP12?

Comment: @MarcWilson   The iPhone6 to iPhone6 app-copy procedure worked for me -on this phone.  It appears to be an iPhone6 to iPhone12 issue.   The fear I have for the "restore backup" is that the instructions say to completely erase the target iPhone.  I'm not going to do that: i want just the Apps and settings restored, not lose the currently installed O/S

Comment: you will not loose the OS, it‘s not part of the backup.

Comment: You never have been able to pair two phones - each wants to be 'master'. This seems part of the same issue as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/464104/restore-from-icloud-backup-without-erasing-all-contents which makes things a little confusing. You are going to get a lot of duplicate information.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to pair them?

Comment: @nohillside  Pairing was attempted through Bluetooth. That had worked for iPhone6 to iPhone6, and the bluetooth allowed them to find each other. But pairing did not work

Comment: You triggered Bluetooth pairing directly from Settings on both iPhones?

Comment: Yes, after pairing did not work from the iPhone12, I also tried from the other direction.  Are you going down the path of "they both tried to be masters?"  In that case we will never know since it might have been a temporary failure and then I put it into a non-workable "who is in charge?" scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reset the phone and was preparing to restore from backup.. but then the two iPhones connected during the setup stage. It is finalizing now after the facial recognition phase on the iPhone12.  So that's .. *interesting* ..  not sure why they recognize each other only during the iPhone12's setup stage.

Comment: because it's not a pairing, it's a specific structure to enable migration, using both bluetooth & wifi. It's easier with newer phones, where you get a shifting pattern of dots you just point the new phone's camera at to initiate the setup.

Comment: ok that makes sense